# How to create an Array for each Array Element?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I just want to have a kind of master `ArrayList` that a user can add elements to (easy enough), but for each one of those elements, I want the user to be able to view another `ArrayList` specific for that element.

As an example, it could be like a custom recipe book - The user adds the name of a meal, and when they select that meal they can view/amend the ingredients required for that meal.

The idea seems pretty straight forward, but I can't find a solution that allows a dynamic list and each item on that list to have another dynamic list.

Comment: Does this differ at all from a List<List<Ingredient>>, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'm going to show is my opinion of a nice design, though know that there are a lot of ways to approach this.

Your master list:

```
List<Meal> meals = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now `Meal` is a class which holds a list of `Ingredient`, and hell, let's give the meal a name!

```
public class Meal{
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;

    //getters, setters, constructor if you will
}
```

Your `Ingredient is then a simple class consisting of whatever you want, for example:

```
public class Ingredient{
    private String name;
    private String grams;

    //getters, setters, constructor if you will
}
```

Depending on what it is you want, this should suffice, you can work with interfaces or super classes if you want to be more flexible as well.

Comment: Perfect, that works a treat on the testing I've done here.  Thanks very much Roel!

Answer (score 0):

I like Roels method and it is the most expandable but here is another way if you dont want to create new classes. have a hashmap of strings to an arraylist of strings.

```
HashMap meals = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList();
ingredients.add("potatoes");
ingredients.add("butter");

meals.put("mashed potatoes",ingredients);
```

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks.  I've found a nice use for this for another project I'm working on :)